# Add a UL to a LI (not add a LI to a UL)

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, html-tree

I am trying to add a UL inside of a LI.  I have an HTML tree that looks like this:

```
<li id="node0"><a href="#" onclick="Collapse(event)"><img src="file:///C:/drag-drop-folder-tree/images/dhtmlgoodies_minus.gif"></a>All My Windows
<ul style="display: block;" id="tree_ul_0">
<li id="node0" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="True"><a href="#">9:00-9:30 moving up</a></li>
<li id="node1" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="True"><a href="#">9:00-9:30 moving down</a>
```

I am trying to use Javascript to add a new UL that will be a child of the LI node0 at the top.

Here is my code:

```
 var newul = document.createElement("ul");


 var ulist = document.getElementById("node0");
 var newItem = document.createElement("li");

 newItem.innerHTML = "<ul id='item1'><li id='Item0' ondragenter='return dragEnter(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' ondrop='drop(event)' ondragstart='drag(event)' draggable='True'><a onclick='Collapse(event)' href='#'><img src='dhtmlgoodies_minus.gif'></a><text>hello</text></li></ul>"

 ulist.appendChild(newItem);
```

When I execute this code, I end up with:

```
<li>
<ul id="item1">
<li id="Item0" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="True"><a onclick="Collapse(event)" href="#"><img src="dhtmlgoodies_minus.gif"></a><text>hello</text>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

So it adds a new:

```
<LI>
```

which is a child of node0

I would like for my item1 UL to be the child of node0.  Can you tell me how to add the UL without getting the extraneous LI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overcomplicated it. You already got the node and you can just set its innerHTML:

```js
var ulist = document.getElementById("node0");

ulist.innerHTML = "<ul id='item1'><li id='Item0' ondragenter='return dragEnter(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' ondrop='drop(event)' ondragstart='drag(event)' draggable='True'><a onclick='Collapse(event)' href='#'><img src='dhtmlgoodies_minus.gif'></a><text>hello</text></li></ul>";
```

Alternatively, you *can* create an ul and an li in it and add that, but then you need to set add the proper element, the ul, to the node. That could easily become a lot of code. The snippet below doesn't even set all events and it doesn't create the `a` element inside the node.

```
var ulist = document.getElementById("node0");

// Create the new ul.
var newul = document.createElement("ul");
newul.id = 'item1';

// Create the new li
var newItem = document.createElement("li");
newitem.id = 'Item0';
newitem.ondragenter = dragEnter;
// ... and so on
newitem.setAttribute('draggable', true);

// Append the li to the ul
newul.appendChild(newItem);
// And append the ul to the parent li.
ulist.appendChild(newul);
```

In your current situation you mixed both. You create a new `ul`, which is never used. Then you create a new `li`. Then you set the innerHTML of that `li` to the entire HTML chunk you want to have, and add it to the parent. The `li` you get in your document is the `newitem` you created in your code.